# Use email address as Woocommerce coupon code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a function to use email address as woocommerce coupon code. My code works perfect before but suddenly it stopped working. I use this `woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data` filter to get the coupon data. Please help me.

```
<?php 
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data', 'firefog_create_coupon', 10, 2  );

function firefog_create_coupon($data, $code) {
    global $wpdb;

    //getting the coupon input value 
    $coupon_code = $_POST['coupon_code'] ;

    //check user input is like email
        if (filter_var($coupon_code, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {  
            $code = $coupon_code ;
        }

    // Check if the coupon has already been created in the database
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = %s AND post_type = 'shop_coupon' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1;", $code );
    $coupon_id = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );

    if ( empty( $coupon_id ) ) {
        // Create a coupon with the properties you need
        $data = array(
            'discount_type'              => 'percent',
            'coupon_amount'              => 15, // value
            'individual_use'             => 'false',
            'product_ids'                => array(),
            'exclude_product_ids'        => array(),
            'usage_limit'                => '',
            'usage_limit_per_user'       => '',//Limit
            'limit_usage_to_x_items'     => '',
            'usage_count'                => '',
            'expiry_date'                => '2020-12-31', // YYYY-MM-DD
            'free_shipping'              => 'false',
            'product_categories'         => array(),
            'exclude_product_categories' => array(),
            'exclude_sale_items'         => 'false',
            'minimum_amount'             => '',
            'maximum_amount'             => '',
            'customer_email'             => array()
        );
        // Save the coupon in the database
        $coupon = array(
            'post_title' => $code,
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => 1,
            'post_type' => 'shop_coupon'
        );
        $new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post( $coupon );
        // Write the $data values into postmeta table
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, $key, $value );
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: try passing id => true to $data returned to filter

Comment: @MujeebuRahman can you show me example of what you mention on passing id? FYI my current code works in two try. first time it create the coupon and when try again it use the coupon. but before woocommerce version 3.0 it works on single try

Comment: $data['id'] = true; return $data;